# Flot shows wrong date from unix

Tags: javascript, unix, date, flot

i have a flot chart that should display two dates in its tooltips.
I have those two unix times,

```
        [data] => 2013-04-17
        [unix] => 1366167600
```

and

```
        [data] => 2013-04-18
        [unix] => 1366254000
```

As you can see, they represent the dates 2013-04-17 and 2013-04-18.

My graph are plotted well, but its tooltips show the same wrong date:
1970-01-16

Any guesses in what that could be?

Thanks.

Comment: `new Date(1366167600*1000)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript date objects use milliseconds, not seconds. Try multiplying your unix timestamp by 1000.

Comment: ra, great! thats it, i tried this before, but i forget to multiply the min and max variables as well! thansk!